# SQL Server INSERT into huge table is slow

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have a large table in a SQl Server 2008 database, it has about 570 million records.
Every day we run a batch job that takes a file of  200,000 or so transaction records, does a group by and sum against this data and inserts it into the large table.

Recently I have experimented with changing the clustered index of the large table to an identity int column, which has brought the insert down from 3 hours to one hour, but I am still puzzled why this simple query should take so long to run (regardless of the size of the table)

This is the table with 570 million rows

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[POINTS_EARNED](
[POINTS_EARNED_ID]int identity not null,
[CARD_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[CYCLE_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[POINTS_CODE] [int] NOT NULL,
[NO_POINTS] [int] NULL,
[ACCOUNT_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[CREATED_DATE] [datetime] NULL,
[CREATED_BY] [varchar](20) NULL,
[LAST_MODIFIED_DATE] [datetime] NULL,
[LAST_MODIFIED_BY] [varchar](20) NULL,
[DELETED] [bit] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_POINTS_EARNED] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[POINTS_EARNED_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, 
IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

) ON [PRIMARY]
```

It also has some constraints (defaults and foreign keys) and indexes, and I am wondering if these are what is causing the problem.

The actual SQL that takes an hour to run is:

```
insert into points_earned (
    card_id,
    cycle_id,
    points_code,
    no_points,
    account_id
    ) 

select pe.card_id, pe.cycle_id, pe.points_code, sum(pe.no_points),pe.account_id
from #points_earned pe 
group by pe.card_id, pe.cycle_id, pe.points_code,pe.account_id
```

and the temp table #points_earned has about 200,000 rows, and has the following structure (with no indexes)

```
create table #points_earned (
        card_id           int,
        cycle_id    int,
        points_code int,
        card_type   varchar(5),
        no_points   int,
        account_id int
        )
```

So, I would like some opinions on whether I should

- Add indexes on the temp table
- Drop non clustered indexes on the large table before adding the data, then recreating them
- Any other options?

**Update - as requested a bit more info**
 - The select statement runs without the insert in 2 seconds, so this doesn't appear to be the problem, so probably don't need o worry about indexing the temp table

Indexes, (update) trigger, and constraints are:

```
    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_CYCLE_ID] ON [dbo].[POINTS_EARNED] 
(
    [CYCLE_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ACCOUNT_ID] ON [dbo].[POINTS_EARNED] 
(
    [ACCOUNT_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ACCOUNT_ID_POINTS_CODE] ON [dbo].[POINTS_EARNED] 
(
    [ACCOUNT_ID] ASC,
    [POINTS_CODE] ASC
)
INCLUDE ( [CARD_ID],
[CYCLE_ID],
[NO_POINTS]) WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [RELATION_151_FK] ON [dbo].[POINTS_EARNED] 
(
    [CARD_ID] ASC,
    [CYCLE_ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [RELATION_152_FK] ON [dbo].[POINTS_EARNED] 
(
    [POINTS_CODE] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [update_points_earned]    Script Date: 09/13/2013 13:20:54 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[update_points_earned] ON [dbo].[POINTS_EARNED]
FOR UPDATE
AS
 BEGIN
  UPDATE points_earned 
  SET Last_Modified_By = USER,
   Last_Modified_Date = GETDATE()  
  FROM
   points_earned t,
   inserted i
  WHERE
   t.card_id = i.card_id AND
   t.cycle_id = i.cycle_id AND
   t.points_code = i.points_code AND
   t.account_id = i.account_id
 END
GO
/****** Object:  Default [DF_POINTS_EARNED_ACCOUNT_ID]    Script Date: 09/13/2013 13:20:54 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[POINTS_EARNED] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_POINTS_EARNED_ACCOUNT_ID]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [ACCOUNT_ID]
GO
/****** Object:  Default [DF_POINTS_EARNED_CREATED_DATE]    Script Date: 09/13/2013 13:20:54 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[POINTS_EARNED] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_POINTS_EARNED_CREATED_DATE]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [CREATED_DATE]
GO
/****** Object:  Default [DF_POINTS_EARNED_CREATED_BY]    Script Date: 09/13/2013 13:20:54 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[POINTS_EARNED] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_POINTS_EARNED_CREATED_BY]  DEFAULT (user_name()) FOR [CREATED_BY]
GO
/****** Object:  Default [DF_POINTS_EARNED_DELETED]    Script Date: 09/13/2013 13:20:54 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[POINTS_EARNED] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_POINTS_EARNED_DELETED]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [DELETED]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [FK_POINTS_E_REFERENCE_CYCLE_CA]    Script Date: 09/13/2013 13:20:54 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[POINTS_EARNED]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_POINTS_E_REFERENCE_CYCLE_CA] FOREIGN KEY([CARD_ID], [CYCLE_ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[CYCLE_CARD] ([CARD_ID], [CYCLE_ID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[POINTS_EARNED] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_POINTS_E_REFERENCE_CYCLE_CA]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [FK_POINTS_E_REFERENCE_POINTS_C]    Script Date: 09/13/2013 13:20:54 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[POINTS_EARNED]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_POINTS_E_REFERENCE_POINTS_C] FOREIGN KEY([POINTS_CODE])
REFERENCES [dbo].[POINTS_CODE] ([POINTS_CODE])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[POINTS_EARNED] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_POINTS_E_REFERENCE_POINTS_C]
GO
/****** Object:  ForeignKey [FK_POINTS_EARNED_REF_ACCOUNT]    Script Date: 09/13/2013 13:20:54 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[POINTS_EARNED]  WITH NOCHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_POINTS_EARNED_REF_ACCOUNT] FOREIGN KEY([ACCOUNT_ID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[ACCOUNT] ([ACCOUNT_ID])
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[POINTS_EARNED] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_POINTS_EARNED_REF_ACCOUNT]
```

**Edit 2, query plan for the insert statement**

```
  |--Sequence
   |--Index Insert(OBJECT:([Progressive_Points].[dbo].[POINTS_EARNED].[IDX_CYCLE_ID]), SET:([POINTS_EARNED_ID1040] = [Progressive_Points].[dbo].[POINTS_EARNED].[POINTS_EARNED_ID],[CYCLE_ID1041] = [Progressive_Points].[dbo].[POINTS_EARNED].[CYCLE_ID]) WITH ORDERED PREFETCH)
   |    |--Sort(ORDER BY:([Progressive_Points].[dbo].[POINTS_EARNED].[CYCLE_ID] ASC, [Progressive_Points].[dbo].[POINTS_EARNED].[POINTS_EARNED_ID] ASC))
   |         |--Table Spool
   |              |--Clustered Index Insert(OBJECT:([Progressive_Points].[dbo].[POINTS_EARNED].[PK_POINTS_EARNED]), SET:([Progressive_Points].[dbo].[POINTS_EARNED].[CARD_ID] = RaiseIfNullInsert([tempdb].[dbo].[#points_earned].[card_id] as [pe].[card_id]),[Progressive_Points].[dbo].[POINTS_EARNED].[CYCLE_ID] = RaiseIfNullInsert([tempdb].[dbo].[#points_earned].[cycle_id] as [pe].[cycle_id]),[Progressive_Points].[dbo].[POINTS_EARNED].[POINTS_CODE] = RaiseIfNullInsert([tempdb].[dbo].[#points_earned].[points_code] as [pe].[points_code]),[Progressive_Points].[dbo].[POINTS_EARNED].[NO_POINTS] = [Expr1006],[Progressive_Points].[dbo].[POINTS_EARNED].[ACCOUNT_ID] = RaiseIfNullInsert([tempdb].[dbo].[#points_earned].[account_id] as [pe].[account_id]),[Progressive_Points].[dbo].[POINTS_EARNED].[POINTS_EARNED_ID] = [Expr1007],[Progressive_Points].[dbo].[POINTS_EARNED].[CREATED_DATE] = [Expr1008],[Progressive_Points].[dbo].[POINTS_EARNED].[CREATED_BY] = [Expr1009],[Progressive_Points].[dbo].[POINTS_EARNED].[DELETED] = [Expr1010],[Progressive_Points].[dbo].[POINTS_EARNED].[LAST_MODIFIED_DATE] = NULL,[Progressive_Points].[dbo].[POINTS_EARNED].[LAST_MODIFIED_BY] = NULL) WITH UNORDERED PREFETCH)
   |                   |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1008]=getdate(), [Expr1009]=CONVERT_IMPLICIT(varchar(20),user_name(),0), [Expr1010]=(0)))
   |                        |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1007]=getidentity((1243867498),(8),NULL)))
   |                             |--Top(ROWCOUNT est 0)
   |                                  |--Parallelism(Gather Streams)
   |                                       |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1006]=CASE WHEN [Expr1062]=(0) THEN NULL ELSE [Expr1063] END))
   |                                            |--Hash Match(Aggregate, HASH:([pe].[card_id], [pe].[cycle_id], [pe].[points_code], [pe].[account_id]), RESIDUAL:([tempdb].[dbo].[#points_earned].[card_id] as [pe].[card_id] = [tempdb].[dbo].[#points_earned].[card_id] as [pe].[card_id] AND [tempdb].[dbo].[#points_earned].[cycle_id] as [pe].[cycle_id] = [tempdb].[dbo].[#points_earned].[cycle_id] as [pe].[cycle_id] AND [tempdb].[dbo].[#points_earned].[points_code] as [pe].[points_code] = [tempdb].[dbo].[#points_earned].[points_code] as [pe].[points_code] AND [tempdb].[dbo].[#points_earned].[account_id] as [pe].[account_id] = [tempdb].[dbo].[#points_earned].[account_id] as [pe].[account_id]) DEFINE:([Expr1062]=COUNT_BIG([tempdb].[dbo].[#points_earned].[no_points] as [pe].[no_points]), [Expr1063]=SUM([tempdb].[dbo].[#points_earned].[no_points] as [pe].[no_points])))
   |                                                 |--Parallelism(Repartition Streams, Hash Partitioning, PARTITION COLUMNS:([pe].[card_id], [pe].[cycle_id], [pe].[points_code], [pe].[account_id]))
   |                                                      |--Clustered Index Scan(OBJECT:([tempdb].[dbo].[#points_earned] AS [pe]))
   |--Index Insert(OBJECT:([Progressive_Points].[dbo].[POINTS_EARNED].[IX_ACCOUNT_ID]), SET:([POINTS_EARNED_ID1042] = [Progressive_Points].[dbo].[POINTS_EARNED].[POINTS_EARNED_ID],[ACCOUNT_ID1043] = [Progressive_Points].[dbo].[POINTS_EARNED].[ACCOUNT_ID]) WITH ORDERED PREFETCH)
   |    |--Sort(ORDER BY:([Progressive_Points].[dbo].[POINTS_EARNED].[ACCOUNT_ID] ASC, [Progressive_Points].[dbo].[POINTS_EARNED].[POINTS_EARNED_ID] ASC))
   |         |--Table Spool
   |--Assert(WHERE:(CASE WHEN [Expr1050] IS NULL THEN (0) ELSE NULL END))
   |    |--Nested Loops(Left Semi Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([Progressive_Points].[dbo].[POINTS_EARNED].[ACCOUNT_ID], [Expr1068]) WITH UNORDERED PREFETCH, DEFINE:([Expr1050] = [PROBE VALUE]))
   |         |--Index Insert(OBJECT:([Progressive_Points].[dbo].[POINTS_EARNED].[IX_ACCOUNT_ID_POINTS_CODE]), SET:([POINTS_EARNED_ID1044] = [Progressive_Points].[dbo].[POINTS_EARNED].[POINTS_EARNED_ID],[CARD_ID1045] = [Progressive_Points].[dbo].[POINTS_EARNED].[CARD_ID],[CYCLE_ID1046] = [Progressive_Points].[dbo].[POINTS_EARNED].[CYCLE_ID],[POINTS_CODE1047] = [Progressive_Points].[dbo].[POINTS_EARNED].[POINTS_CODE],[NO_POINTS1048] = [Progressive_Points].[dbo].[POINTS_EARNED].[NO_POINTS],[ACCOUNT_ID1049] = [Progressive_Points].[dbo].[POINTS_EARNED].[ACCOUNT_ID]) WITH UNORDERED PREFETCH)
   |         |    |--Table Spool
   |         |--Clustered Index Seek(OBJECT:([Progressive_Points].[dbo].[ACCOUNT].[PK_ACCOUNT]), SEEK:([Progressive_Points].[dbo].[ACCOUNT].[ACCOUNT_ID]=[Progressive_Points].[dbo].[POINTS_EARNED].[ACCOUNT_ID]) ORDERED FORWARD)
   |--Assert(WHERE:(CASE WHEN [Expr1054] IS NULL THEN (0) ELSE NULL END))
   |    |--Nested Loops(Left Semi Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([Progressive_Points].[dbo].[POINTS_EARNED].[CARD_ID], [Progressive_Points].[dbo].[POINTS_EARNED].[CYCLE_ID], [Expr1070]) WITH UNORDERED PREFETCH, DEFINE:([Expr1054] = [PROBE VALUE]))
   |         |--Index Insert(OBJECT:([Progressive_Points].[dbo].[POINTS_EARNED].[RELATION_151_FK]), SET:([POINTS_EARNED_ID1051] = [Progressive_Points].[dbo].[POINTS_EARNED].[POINTS_EARNED_ID],[CARD_ID1052] = [Progressive_Points].[dbo].[POINTS_EARNED].[CARD_ID],[CYCLE_ID1053] = [Progressive_Points].[dbo].[POINTS_EARNED].[CYCLE_ID]) WITH ORDERED PREFETCH)
   |         |    |--Sort(ORDER BY:([Progressive_Points].[dbo].[POINTS_EARNED].[CARD_ID] ASC, [Progressive_Points].[dbo].[POINTS_EARNED].[CYCLE_ID] ASC, [Progressive_Points].[dbo].[POINTS_EARNED].[POINTS_EARNED_ID] ASC))
   |         |         |--Table Spool
   |         |--Row Count Spool
   |              |--Index Seek(OBJECT:([Progressive_Points].[dbo].[CYCLE_CARD].[IDX_NCLST_CARD_ID_CYCLE_ID]), SEEK:([Progressive_Points].[dbo].[CYCLE_CARD].[CARD_ID]=[Progressive_Points].[dbo].[POINTS_EARNED].[CARD_ID] AND [Progressive_Points].[dbo].[CYCLE_CARD].[CYCLE_ID]=[Progressive_Points].[dbo].[POINTS_EARNED].[CYCLE_ID]) ORDERED FORWARD)
   |--Assert(WHERE:(CASE WHEN [Expr1057] IS NULL THEN (0) ELSE NULL END))
        |--Merge Join(Left Semi Join, MANY-TO-MANY MERGE:([Progressive_Points].[dbo].[POINTS_EARNED].[POINTS_CODE])=([Progressive_Points].[dbo].[POINTS_CODE].[POINTS_CODE]), RESIDUAL:([Progressive_Points].[dbo].[POINTS_EARNED].[POINTS_CODE]=[Progressive_Points].[dbo].[POINTS_CODE].[POINTS_CODE]))
             |--Index Insert(OBJECT:([Progressive_Points].[dbo].[POINTS_EARNED].[RELATION_152_FK]), SET:([POINTS_EARNED_ID1055] = [Progressive_Points].[dbo].[POINTS_EARNED].[POINTS_EARNED_ID],[POINTS_CODE1056] = [Progressive_Points].[dbo].[POINTS_EARNED].[POINTS_CODE]) WITH ORDERED PREFETCH)
             |    |--Sort(ORDER BY:([Progressive_Points].[dbo].[POINTS_EARNED].[POINTS_CODE] ASC, [Progressive_Points].[dbo].[POINTS_EARNED].[POINTS_EARNED_ID] ASC))
             |         |--Table Spool
             |--Index Scan(OBJECT:([Progressive_Points].[dbo].[POINTS_CODE].[POINTS_CODES_PK]), ORDERED FORWARD)
```

Comment: 1) show us the index and key definitions, 2) how long does that `select` take to execute without the `insert`?, and 3) are there any Triggers on this table?  Also, the query plan of the INSERT would be very helpful to answering your question.

Comment: There's a lot of factors that go into performance issue with large bulk inserts.  I had to import (in Test) 7 million lines of information with Sequence statements on a VM.  The only way I was able to find to run this query was to create just straight T-sql code.  I ran into issues with memory right off the bat as the VM would only allow about 3 million or so lines before the memory was fully eaten up.  I would throw a performance monitor on the process focusing on the disk, and memory first.

Comment: The first thing that I'd do is try to figure out whether your performance problem is with the select/group by or with the bulk insert.

Obviously, you've thought about this already, since your first option (adding indexes on the temp table) addresses the first, and your second option (dropping/adding the indexes on the target table) addresses the second.

I wouldn't be surprised if both of these things were issues.
Why not try both, and see if one or both options help?

Comment: Are you experiencing any file growth (database or log) during the inserts? Look at [Aaron Bertrand's blog](https://sqlblog.org/2007/01/11/reviewing-autogrow-events-from-the-default-trace) Are there corresponding growth events with your data load?

Comment: Also, with your switch from a natural key to a surrogate key, your trigger should be updated. While old school joins are still supported, for maintainability, write it as `points_earned t inner join inserted i on i.POINTS_EARNED_ID = t.POINTS_EARNED_ID`

Comment: I don't think file growth is the problem, I have the DB in simple recovery mode in our dev environment and we still have the same issues -good point about the trigger!

Comment: I have the same problem, after removing 10% or more of the data or moved to another datable  or deleted, the database starts to low query execution in general on table no related with removed data. No solution found so far, removing a lot of data slow also bulk insert with 1k-5k records each time inserted.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

OK, here's what I would do:

1. Check to see if you need both indexes [IX_ACCOUNT_ID_POINTS_CODE] and [IX_ACCOUNT_ID] as they may be redundant.
2. Before you do the `INSERT`, Disable the Trigger and drop the Foreign Keys.
3. Do the `INSERT` setting the fields normally set by the Trigger, and insuring that the FK Column's values are valid.
4. Re-Enable the trigger, and re-create the Foreign Keys WITH NOCHECK.

I would leave the indexes on as you are inserting less than 0.2% of the total row count so it's probably faster to update them in-place rather than to drop and rebuild them.

Comment: I've marked this as the correct answer. The problem seems to be with the foreign keys, one of them in particular didn't seem to have a very good index on the parent table, and was taking about 80% of the query time. Dropping the FKs and recreating has taken the job down to 5 minutes or so (I need to re-restore the databases and run the whole process from scratch to take caching out of the performance change)

Comment: 2 years later this answer helped me get a script that was taking 50-60 seconds down to 5 seconds. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

instead of deleting 200k rows from the massive table in one shot, try chunking it. E.g.:

```
while (1=1)
begin
  delete top(1000) from #points_earned
  output deleted.* into points_earned
  if @@rowcount=0 break
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your TABLE, there's 3 considerations that affects your performance for each record you add :
(1) Your Indexes
(2) Your Trigger
(3) Your Foreign Keys

If you can afford it, apply the appropriate architecture for your TABLE, like PARTITION TABLE, and PARTITION INDEXES within appropriate SAS Drives.

Otherwise, on similar situation, with dozen of thousands records updated every minute, i use the technique of BULK/INSERT, with another TABLE (ex. [POINTS_EARNED_TMP] on a separate Database within the same Instance (*).

Add the record with the Trigger [POINTS_EARNED_TMP]. 
Then, from another BULK, you set your procedure with no triggers and BULK/INSERT your data from [POINTS_EARNED_TMP] to [POINTS_EARNED] (including the USER, and DATE Update).
At least, the Trigger performance is avoided, and the #TMP within the same Instance is avoided too.

(*) Using another Database is mainly for maintenance reason. 
BULK gives so far, amazing results compare to the INSERT TO.

Comment: I don't think the trigger is causing me a problem at the moment, because it is an UPDATE trigger, and my issue is with an INSERT statement. I suspect the indexes and foreign keys are the real issue here. I'll try running the code with the trigger disabled though and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I'm convince that BULK will give better performance than INSERT TO (if you don't have a constraint on file written to disk, ofc).

Comment: Otherwise, did you have a look to your indexes usage statistics (DB, Report) ?
Here a better understanding, in how it can help you too : https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/tune-your-indexing-strategy-with-sql-server-dmvs/

Comment: Cheers Little Buddy, You may be right on the bulk insert. It will take me a day or so to restore the database back to the position I can generate a queryplan, but I will post it when I have it