# Batch insert in JDBC taking long time

Tags: java, jdbc, bulkinsert

I tried to batch insert 10K record by jdbc connection in MSSQL, it took around 18 to 20 secs to bulk insert. I want to insert in less than 3 seconds. Is there any way to insert quickly.

**My code given below**

```
public void BatchInsert() {
    PreparedStatement pStmnt = null;
  try {
     final int batchSize = 1000;
     int count = 0;
     Connection con = createConnection();
     long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
     System.out.println("connection creation time :: " + (end - start));
     start = System.currentTimeMillis();
     pStmnt = con.prepareStatement("insert into testtable values(?)");
     for (int i = 1; i <= 10000; i++) {
        pStmnt.setInt(1, i);
        pStmnt.addBatch();

       if (++count % batchSize == 0) {
          pStmnt.executeBatch();
       }
     }
     pStmnt.executeBatch(); // insert remaining records
     end = System.currentTimeMillis();
     System.out.println("total insert time :: " + (end - start));
 } catch (SQLException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 } finally {
     try {
       pStmnt.close();
     } catch (SQLException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }
    }
```

Thanks in advance for yr help.

Comment: Try turning off autoCommit on your connection, and committing manually after the `executeBatch()`.  Whether this will make a difference is implementation-defined, but if it *does* make a difference then it could be huge.  Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19536513/addbatch-used-together-with-autocommit-true

Comment: Note also: I see your code obtaining a `Connection`, but never closing it or otherwise releasing it.  I don't know exactly what `createConnection()` does, but it's hard to believe that you're not leaking connections.

Comment: @JohnBollinger re: *"if it does make a difference then it could be huge"* - My own quick test before posting my answer showed `con.setAutoCommit(false)` and `con.commit()` reduced the execution time to about 1/100 of the time required for `con.setAutoCommit(true)`.

Answer (score 0):

As far I think that, you have used more indexing in your database table. That's why it is taking more time. For this reason, in inserting case, at first you need to stop indexing somehow(maybe deleting and recreating or removing unnecessary indexing).

For operational purpose, you can remove all indexing from your `testtable` and run your batch. Hopefully you will get minimal insertion time.

### Resource Link:

1. [More indexes, slower INSERT - Use The Index, Luke!](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/dml/insert)
2. [Fundamentals: Improving Insert and Update Performance by Dropping
   Unused Indexes.](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sql_server_isv/2011/04/15/fundamentals-improving-insert-and-update-performance-by-dropping-unused-indexes/)

### UPDATE:

1. Before you do the INSERT, Disable the Trigger and drop the Foreign
   Keys.
2. Do the INSERT setting the fields normally set by the Trigger, and
   insuring that the FK Column's values are valid.
3. Re-Enable the trigger, and re-create the Foreign Keys WITH NOCHECK.

Credit goes to [@RBarryYoung](https://stackoverflow.com/users/109122/rbarryyoung)

### Resource Link:

1. [SQL Server INSERT into huge table is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18775475/sql-server-insert-into-huge-table-is-slow)

Answer (score 0):

If your connection is defaulting to AutoCommit mode then you may get some significant improvement in performance by doing

```java
con.setAutoCommit(false);
```

before entering the loop to `addBatch`, and then doing

```java
con.commit();
```

after the final `executeBatch`.