# Slow insert: select from view

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert, sql-view

The following statement takes at least 4 seconds:

```
INSERT INTO [SomeSmallTable] 
SELECT * FROM ComplexView 
WHERE [Date] = convert(datetime, '23/09/2020',103)
```

However, if we only run the SELECT part without the INSERT INTO, it takes less than half a second:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ComplexView 
WHERE [Date] = convert(datetime, '23/09/2020',103)
```

The view selects less than 200 rows, and the table called "SomeSmallTable" holds only a few rows. I think this issue started when we updated the view called "ComplexView". ComplexView is based on other views (and some of these views are based on other views itself), as well as some tables.

I tried to refresh all views using `sp_refreshview`, but to no avail.

How can we determine the cause of this issue and hopefully solve it?

---

[EDIT]

My reply to some comments:

- @Dale K: I can't post the execution plans, I think they way to complex, and not relevant as they are equal for both statements, with or without the INSERT part, except for the Table Insert part. But I did see that the INSERT costs 100%. For some reason SQL has trouble inserting the view results in the table.
- @Panagiotis Kanavos: Nobody but me is using the database. It's a copy of our clients database and I'm working on it on my local machine.
- @gotqn: SomeSmallTable is a table, so no table variable or temporary table. However, it is created when a user opens a specific form in our application, and deleted then the user closes this form.
- @Arvo: SomeSmallTable has no keys and no triggers. The view returns less than 200 rows which are inserted in this table, and before these are inserted the table is empty.
- I followed the steps in the accepted answer, and eventually compared the current "ComplexView" with the previous version, and found out what caused this issue.

Comment: Inspect the execution plans? And post them here?

Comment: Who else is using that table? If it's locked for reading by other connections/transactions, the INSERT will have to wait before it can modify the contents.

Comment: In any case, a query is never executed as-is. It's compiled into an execution plan. That's why you should *always* inspect the execution plan when you have performance problems.

Comment: What is  `[SomeSmallTable]` a SQL table, table variable or temporary table?

Comment: Does your `SomeSmallTable` have primary key? Does it have triggers defined?

Comment: Maybe you should create it with primary key (identity) then and use specified columns list for insertion. Or use temporary table for complex query results and insert data from temporary table - sometimes helps.

Comment: Also note that the 100% figure given in SSMS execution plans is an estimate rather than an actual. It can often be seriously wrong. If you use the later versions of SSMS, the times on each step can often be a better indicator of ... err... what's taking the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the execution plan is the first step, as others have said. Given that the `INSERT` (rather than the query) is causing the delay, you could troubleshoot that further. Here are some things you can try:

- Try using Statistics IO to find out more, as answered [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/482/how-can-i-tell-why-an-insert-on-a-certain-table-is-slow).
- Attempt an `INSERT` using static data (e.g. `INSERT INTO [SomeSmallTable] VALUES (1, 2, '...etc');`). This will tell you if the issue is any `INSERT` statement, or when inserting from a view specifically.
- Check how much data the view is returning. 4s may or may not be reasonable, depending on how many rows are being inserted.
- Check the table design to see how it is using primary keys, foreign keys, composite keys, indexes, triggers, etc. Some of these features optimise a table's design for selecting, but make insertion slower as a trade-off. A good answer about this can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18777063).
- If you know it's not a load issue (because you're the only one using this database), check whether something else might be restricting resources on the machine you're using (other resource-intensive tasks, any other queries happening at the same time, scheduled jobs within SQL Server, etc.) You can use [SQL Server Profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-ver15) to watch the queries in real time.
- If slow performance is not limited to this particular query, then there are other general [design considerations](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2020/02/10/sql-server-top-reasons-for-slow-performance/) you can look into.

Comment: I think this is a decent troubleshooting approach. One other step you could try is to split the insert into two steps e.g., `SELECT * INTO #temptable FROM ...` and then `INSERT INTO SomeSmallTable SELECT * FROM #temptable`. If this works fine then I suspect the execution plans between the two statements (SELECT and INSERT) are slightly different - particularly if one of the views uses SomeSmallTable.

Comment: I was going to also suggest trying a `BULK INSERT` from another source (e.g. a CSV file) if many rows are involved. You're right, a temp table would be another way to check that.

Comment: @sbgib I'm not familiar with statistics. I guess I have to use SET STATISTICS ON, so I did. It's returning some high values for scan count (highest: 186) and logical reads (highest 663 up to 3635) for a number of tables which are queried by the view. For 1 table 305 read-ahead reads and 1 physical reads for another table. I also inserted the records to another table, and inserted these records to "SomeSmallTable", which was fast. So inserting from the view is slow, and from static data fast. The view returns like 93 rows (and 217 columns!). The view may be the issue after all.

Comment: The issue was related to a change in "ComplexView" which for some reason caused this view to insert slow in "SomeSmallTable". Following the steps in the accepted answer helped me find this solution, especcially using Statistics IO.

Comment: Nice! :) Glad to hear you found the cause! I was not too familiar with statistics myself, had to [look it up](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-statistics-io-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) too. Sounds like you were able to work out that the design of 'SomeSmallTable' couldn't be the issue, as static data and data from the other table was quick to insert. In any case, the 'ComplexView' being the cause makes it sound like changing the view design was the most straighforward solution (e.g. changing the combination of joins, sub-queries, etc.)